# How to Copy SSIS Package from MSDB Database to File System using ssms or ssis Package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

Is there a Way to Copy `SSIS` Package from MSDB Database to File System using `SSMS` or `SSIS` Package.

My attempts where:

1. using `dtutil` with `xp_cmdshell` in `SSMS QUERY`

   ```
   EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dtutil  /sourceserver  SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME /SQL "\TestingData\Package" /copy file;"c:\Package.dtsx"'
   ```

*result:*

[image]

*NOTE: no problem when using `xp_cmdshell` without `dtutil` since i made a successful 'File Copy'.*

2. my second attempt was the same but using `SSIS` component `Execute Process task`.

[image]

**BUT the result was:**

> Error: 0xC0029151 at Execute Process Task, Execute Process Task: In Executing "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" "dtutil  /sourceserver  servername\instancename /SQL "\TestingData\Package" /copy file;"c:\Package.dtsx"" at "", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".
>   Task failed: Execute Process Task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Suggestions

There many things to take into consideration:

1. In the first screenshot, the output your are getting is that **Access is denied**, so first check that you have write permissions on `C:\` drive, or try copying to another path.
2. Try reordering the parameters you are passing to the dtutil tool and remove the `\` before the package path:

   ```
   EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dtutil /SQL TestingData\Package /sourceserver SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME /Copy File;"c:\Package.dtsx"'
   ```
3. You must have a windows authentication on the SQL instance you are connecting to, in the command above , so if you don't have this type of authentication, try using an SQL authentication:

   ```
   EXEC xp_cmdshell 'dtutil /SQL TestingData\Package /SourceServer SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME /SourceUser Monkey_User /SourcePassword P@$$word /Copy file;"c:\Package.dtsx"'
   ```

## References

- [dtutil Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/dtutil-utility)
- [DTUTIL Utility to Copy / Delete SSIS Deployed in MSDB to File System](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/63263/)
- [Using dtutil to copy SSIS packages stored in SQL Server](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3734096/Using-dtutil-to-copy-SSIS-packages-stored-in-SQL-Server.htm)
- [SSIS Command Line Utilities part 1: dtutil](http://www.bimonkey.com/2010/01/ssis-command-line-utilities-part-1-dtutil/)

Comment: 1- as i mentioned above, there is no problem using `xp_cmdshell` to copy a file from one location to another. 2- i have no problem using `dtutil` outside `ssms` or `ssis`.

Comment: it seems that the first suggestion was the missing one for me, since i tried the same query on another drive successfully, after making `Full Control` on `C` drive, error disappeared. the confusing thing is that i tried the same query from `dtutil` directly with no problem, and failed executing query using `WindowsAuthentication` or 'SqlServerAuthentication'.

Comment: @mhdsweidan take a look https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/4a727a29-3696-4dd3-9348-0146989407b8/execute-xpcmdshell-with-sysadmin-login-details?forum=transactsql

Comment: @mhdsweidan have you try it again using execute process task from SSIS

Comment: @mhdsweidan i think that the xp_cmdshell is executed with the Windows account that the SQL Server service is running under.  Specifically, you can find this within SQL Server Configuration Manager. So it will still throwing access denied if this account doesn't have the privileges on the destination path

Comment: package executed successfully by replacing path of `cmd.exe` to  `dtutil.exe` in `Executable Property` and removed "xp_cmdshell 'dtutil" while passing arguments. thanks a lot